# Reading and comparing coordinates from Excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas, math, coordinates

I was hoping to get some advice or help if possible. This is my first ever coding project so if my questions too vague or if anything else needs work on my end please let me know.

I have two different (x,y) coordinates stored in an excel sheet. First thing I need to do is write a code that can read these in as (x,y) coordinates and then determine their proximity.

Heres where I am at:

```
import math
import pandas
file1 = pandas.read_excel('Book1.xlsx')
file2 = pandas.read_excel('\Book2.xlsx')
# reads various text files and prints them into PyCharm
file1['x_diff'] = file2['x'] - file1['x']
file1['y_diff'] = file2['y'] - file1['y']
dist = file1.apply(lambda row: math.hypot(row['x_diff'], row['y_diff']),   axis=1)
print dist
print file2.head()
print file1.head()
```

Heres the result! Just a few quick last questions here.

```
0    4.472136
dtype: float64
   x  y
0  12 -3
   x  y  x_diff  y_diff
0  8 -5       4       2
```

Again anything which might be able to steer me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. Cheers!

Comment: You are importing pandas again in the 4th line of your code. You can continue to use a module again and again after you import it once.

Comment: Thanks I fixed that

Comment: do you want to calculate the hypot between all combinations of points from both files (i.e. all points from file1 with first_poin, point2, ..., last_point from file2)?

Comment: Yes that is exactly the end goal here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way for a starter would be to:

1.Calculate the difference in x and y for the whole table:

```
table1['x_diff'] = table2['x'] - table1['x']
table1['y_diff'] = table2['y'] - table1['y']
```

2.Apply your function to the new columns:

```
dist = table1.apply(lambda row: math.hypot(row['x_diff'], row['y_diff']), axis=1)
```

Now your `dist` variable contains the distance you can analyse.

Comment: Awesome thanks so much I made these adjustments and it seems promising but I am still having an issue it seems. I posted the edits for the code above and the resulting error message.

Comment: @JustinT why did you change pandas pandas.read_excel to this open? Sure that would not work, as now it is just a file stream and not a pandas data frame. Rollback to the pandas read and everything should work like a charm!

Comment: I tried making that adjustment and got kicked back again with an issue. Made the edits above again. Thanks for help and patience!

Comment: @JustinT you don't need to pass 'r' as a second parameter into pandas.read_excel function — it means that you want to read a spreadsheet with title 'r',which is, obviously, missing.

Comment: Tried that as well and posted the new code along with error message above.

Comment: Well, as the error message says — there is no key 'x' in your excel file! Change the x and y to the real names of the coordinates, print the file2.head() to see what you have read from the file.

Comment: Dude that mostly fixed all the errors! Man I feel dumb making some of those mistakes. The code is working without errors after I went back into the Excel document and added column names. One final question. In the final draft of the code, the reader is giving what I put above. What is the 0 next to the read in of linear distance value?

Comment: It is just an index, from 0 to n in your case. Since it seems like you only have one row, it is zero. Good luck!

Comment: any advice on getting rid of the unnecessary output? I need to run a >,<, or = for the answer output and cant in this current format.